# Enable trackpad tap-to-click in BootCamp on 1st-gen (non-multi-touch) MacBook?

Tags: windows, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, boot-camp, touchpad

Apparently, the trackpad driver in later model MacBooks (those with multi-touch trackpads) has trackpad tap-to-click support. Is there any way to enable this in Boot Camp on a *first-generation* MacBook?

I'm running with the latest Boot Camp update (2.1) and Apple drivers. I've tried both XP+SP3, Vista, and Windows 7 RC under Boot Camp and haven't been able to figure this out in either environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be available with an update to Boot Camp 3.0 included in Snow Leopard.

From [Boot Camp 3.0 FAQ page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3777):

> - **Improved tap-to-click support** - The
>     ability to tap the trackpad to click
>     the mouse button is now supported on
>     all Mac portables that run Boot Camp.

Comment: Excellent! I'm unable to verify this before the bounty ends, since my copy of Snow Leopard won't arrive until after that, but it sounds like it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in Windows 7, but in XP SP3 it is an option in the Boot Camp item under Control Panel.
After you install all the junk from the OSX DVD, there should be a Boot Camp icon in the Control Panel (should look like [this](http://www.iconarchive.com/icons/mcdo-design/cats/Boot-Camp-128x128.png)).  There is a "Keyboard" or "Mouse" tab in there which will give you the options for tapping, right-tapping, multi-touch, etc.

### Update

It seems that this solution is only available with the newer unibody MacBook Pros, and may not work for everyone.  Check out the comments thread for more info.

Comment: Hmm, not seeing this. Do you have a screenshot? Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I added a bit more details and an SC.  You did install all the drivers from the DVD, right?

Comment: Yeah, I've installed the drivers from the DVD. I don't see the option in this screen capture -- I've looked at all the tabs in the Boot Camp control panel and don't see the option I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you guess this or you've actually done this? Since I'm pretty sure there's no official way to do this. You can find lots of request on Apple discussion boards about this.

Comment: I use this on my Macbook Pro at home, and it works fine.  `o.O;`

Comment: I wonder if maybe it's only available with the newer multi-touch trackpads?

Comment: Maybe on the *newer* multitouch trackpads, since it's not available on my first generation MacBook Air (which does have multitouch but not four finger gestures).

Comment: Added a new screeny.  It's there.
Have you checked to see if there are any updates from Software Update within Windows?  You may need to install iTunes to get the updater.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the "Trackpad" tab in my control panel, but I'm pretty sure I'm running the latest version of Boot Camp. Software Update is not showing any updates.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do you see the "Trackpad" tab in your Boot Camp control panel?

Comment: Not sure, then.  It may be, as Mehrdad said, a newer trackpad thing.  This MBP is the first I've ever turned it on for, so the first time I've looked for it.  Beyond latest drivers/boot camp, I'm not really sure.  `=-[`

Answer (score 0):

The Snow Leopard DVD includes BootCamp 3.0.  All trackpads can tap click with this version of BootCamp.  I know it works (very well I might add) in at least XP and Vista.  I do not know about Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I've all the features working on mousepad in Windows 7 64 Bit. Single tap on the trackpad, 2 finger tap for right click... finally got everything working on my Macbook 2008 (White) for Windows 7 64 Bit. Its pretty fast for my 2GB RAM, booting up, shutting down. Upgraded my HDD from 160GB 5400rpm to 500GB 7200 RPM. Divided equally into 250/250 gig....

Answer (score 0):

That's Easy to activate tap to click in windows 7 on bootcamp
you mean tapping is not working and u must push pad hardly how to solve?

just do right click on bootcamp icon on traybar
go to bootcamp control panel
last tab "TrackPad" activate the Tap to click